# AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'angle' - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am working on generating an animation with a moving rectangle using *matplotlib.animation*.

To do so, I first create a Rectangle (matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) at initialisation and then, within the loop, I set its coordinates, size and orientation using methods as *set_height*, *set_width*, etc.

However, nor the method *set_angle* nor *set(angle = 30.)* allow me to set the orientation of my rectangle and an error is thrown. On the other hand, both methods are supposed to be implemented, according to matplotlib documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html).

Here's a very basic example that gives the same error (line 19)  :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xy = [0, 0]
width = 10.
height = 5.
theta = 30.

patch = patches.Rectangle([0.5, 0.5], 0.3, 0.1,60.0, edgecolor='black', linewidth = 2,   fc='r')

ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show

patch.set_width(0.4)
patch.set_height(0.2)
#patch.set_angle(70.)
plt.show
```

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The documentation that you link to doesn't seem to have an entry for `set_angle`, so I don't understand your claim that it does.

Comment: Have you tried `patch.angle = 30.0`?